# Decoding Base64 in C# sometimes gives incorrect result with one extra padding character

Tags: c#, .net, base64

I stumbled upon a strange behavior of `Convert.FromBase64String` in .NET 4.7.2. Normally it would throw an exception when the padding is not correct. But I found a case where adding another padding character produces an incorrect result instead of an exception.

```cs
var correct = Convert.FromBase64String("YWE=");
```

In this case `correct` is `[97, 97]` or `"aa"` in a string form. But when I add another `=`:

```cs
var incorrect = Convert.FromBase64String("YWE==");
```

instead of getting an exception I get one byte less and `incorrect` is `[88]` or `"X"` is a string form.

Weird. Is this a bug and it should be reported? Or is it a known/documented behavior? I couldn't find any references to this.

Compare to Ruby. This evaluates to `"aa"`:

```rb
Base64.strict_decode64 "YWE="
```

And this raises an exception:

```rb
Base64.strict_decode64 "YWE=="

ArgumentError: invalid base64
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/base64.rb:74:in `unpack1'
```

Comment: And [other](https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode) [decoders](https://www.base64decode.org/) [also](http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/) [pass](https://www.base64decode.net/) fine. There is no bug.

Comment: @DavidG, all these decoders seem to ignore the padding and decode to `"aa"`, which is correct. None of them decode to `"X"`. Must be a bug.

Comment: Actually the first one adds a unicode character on the end. The point is that the Base64 you supply is invalid, there is no "bug".

Comment: @DavidG, yes, it's invalid. I expect an exception, like if I add one more `=`. I don't expect an incorrect answer.

Comment: Looks at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.7.2) though, it will throw a `FormatException` if the string *contains a non-base-64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space-character among the padding characters.*

Comment: Looks like a bug that was fixed in .NET Core :https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/30814

Comment: @DavidG, exactly, it should throw an exception but it doesn't

Comment: I stumbled upon this bug right now, wanted to report it to the Developer Community tracker, found your report, and arrived here. Bad luck I did not find it at the beginning…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30793
It's fixed in .NET Core but still present in .NET Framework up to and including 4.8.

This code should abort with exception instead of printing `1`:

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.FromBase64String("YWE==").Length);
    }
}
```

Here's a test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x2X9CT