# Convert.ToBase64String/Convert.FromBase64String doesn't return the original string value

Tags: c#, .net, base64, tobase64string

```
"encryptedHelloWorld=" ==
      Convert.ToBase64String(
         Convert.FromBase64String("encryptedHelloWorld="))
```

This statement returns false

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Convert.FromBase64String("encryptedHelloWorld="))
```

return `"encryptedHelloWorlc="`

Any idea why?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54852219/decoding-base64-in-c-sharp-sometimes-gives-incorrect-result-with-one-extra-paddi/54852796#54852796

Comment: Related in a general sense only - that example is one with an incorrect padding ("extra padding character"), not extra-bits-in-characters next to a valid padding. If changing that example from "YWE==" to "YWE=", it round-trips correctly. The specific [now resolved in some framework] issue where an exception was not thrown and a character *previous to padded characters* was incorrectly handled was for a different case of errors. I'm not sure if the .NET Core fixes handles (ie. throws) if invalid padding char bits are used, as is the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original value of `encryptedHelloWorld=` is *not* correctly base-64 encoded.

The last "d" contains an extra bit that is ignored on extraction in this context, where it occurs *immediately before padding*. A stricter base-64 decoder could validly throw an error.

Minimal failing input cases include `rld=` or `abq=`. Only the last portion with the padding is relevant, as discussed below.

Consider that each output character of base-64 character represent *6 bits each*.

Thus the information encoded in `rld=` is:

- `r` - 6 bits
- `l` - 6 bits
- `d` - 6 bits (4 relevant = "c" + 2 extra)
- `=` - n/a

This must be extracted into 2 bytes (8 + 8 = 16 bits).

However, 6 + 6 + 6 = 18 bits and is *not* a multiple of 8. There are 2 *extra* bits which differentiate "c" from "d" in the initial base-64 value *which do not reflect the actual encoded information*.

During the decoding, the .NET decoder implementation *silently drops* the two extra bits in the "d", as they have nowhere to go. (This is also true for cases like `abq=` as "q" > "c"; note that capital letters are ordered first in the base-64 output space so "Q" < "c".)

In the normal case without padding, every 4 base-64 characters decode in 3 bytes evenly, which is why this particular issue is only present at the end of a base-64 string which is not an even multiple of 4 base-64 characters (excluding padding characters).

Comment: Does it mean one cannot encode any string ending with "=" sign in base64 without risking an unexpected behavior ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `=` itself. That is the padding character _in the output_.

Comment: Ooooh okay, I didn't notice the original code was using `FromBase64`.